# Make mpv display name of youtube link when playing just audio

Tags: youtube-dl, mpv

When playing just the audio from a youtube link, you have some thing like this:

```
mpv '<youtube_link>' --no-video
```

and when the song starts to play you have this on the terminal:

```
AO: [pulse] 44100Hz stereo 2ch float
A: 00:00:40 / 00:31:39 (2%) Cache: 10s+16498KB
```

or something similar.

Is there a way to display the link name (the name of the link being played)?

When you just play a normal video, the name is at the top of the window, and above the controls.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have a script that I use just for exactly that purpose.  It looks as follows:

```
#!/bin/sh
if [[ "x$1" == "x" ]]; then
  echo "Usage: mpvy <URL>"
else
  title=`youtube-dl --skip-download --get-title $1`
  mpv --no-video --term-playing-msg "### $title ###" $1
fi
```

If you are already using `mpv` to watch/listen to youtube clips then you should have `youtube-dl` installed since it is what `mpv` uses to download the youtube clip.

It is a little rough of a solution (e.g. does not work with several links at once) but serves its purpose.  And can be easily extended using a for loop.

Comment: I have `youtube-dl`, that's why I put in the tag. Thanks the script! I have a question. I understand everything except the condition in the beginning. You are testing if the user has submitted a empty argument. Why is the `x` necessary? Couldn't you just check if it was an empty string?

Comment: @smrdo_prdo - That `x` is just an old scripting habit.  Some versions of `ksh` (and some other ancient shells) did not properly evaluate a condition against an empty string.  That happened because they dropped the quotes before the comparison ending in `[[ $1 == ]]`, which would be a syntax error.

Comment: This does not work for playlists.

Answer (score 5):

#### Method 1:

Add `term-playing-msg="Title: ${media-title}"` to your mpv.conf

#### Method 2:

Add `--term-playing-msg='Title: ${media-title}'` to your command

```
mpv --term-playing-msg='Title: ${media-title}' <YOUR_VIDEO_LINK>
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer cause it works also with playlists.

Comment: This is a better solution than the one in the accepted answer. It works well with playlists and multiple files arguments, and it doesn't require a separate youtube-dl invocation just to get the file title.

Comment: perfect, thx - I love mpv :)